# How do I get NSNumber with NSLocale smarts from a UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

Getting correct localized formatting of numbers to display is easy.
But prompting for a decimal number input from a UITextField is proving tricky.

Even though the decimal keypad may present the comma for European usage instead of the stop, the method handling the input apparently still needs to be locale-savvy.

my research here on S.O. and other places suggests

```
-(IBAction)buttonPress:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSNumber *firstNumber  = @([self.firstField.text floatValue]); // 2 alternative ways
NSNumber *secondNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.secondField.text floatValue]];    
.
.
```

only gives me integers to perform arithmetic with. They aren't floats at all. They have no float value

Supposing this is the only thing the app does, and I immediately do:

```
.
.
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormat = [[ NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[ numberFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[ numberFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[ numberFormat setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSString *displayString = [ numberFormat stringFromNumber:firstNumber];
self.resultLabel.text = displayString;
}
```

I am throwing the input back to a label in the ViewController without any further handling to make sure the the decimals aren't hidden by not having a formatter. No Joy. Still in integers.

Obviously the app has to do something in the way of calculation, and since one can't handle NSNumber wrappers directly, I have to resolve it before i do the conversion thing:

```
double xD = [firstNumber  doubleValue];
double yD = [secondNumber doubleValue];
```

the question is, where is the decimal-ness of the input being lost?
I have no problem with the desktop keyboard and the simulator, but if i set a test device to - say - Polish then that simply won't do.

EDIT:
and here's the result from the answer provided below

```
// run these 4 methods first, that way you can re-use *numberFormat for the display
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormat = [[ NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[ numberFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[ numberFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[ numberFormat setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

// here 'tis
NSNumber *firstNumber = [numberFormat numberFromString:self.firstField.text];
// do the same for other input UITextFields
// sh-boom. there you go
```

Comment: I should add getting regular input then converting to NSNumber is just as fruitless. The method doesn't know what the comma is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use longLongValue not longValue to convert **NSString** to long type. or use **NSNumberFormatter**->`numberFromString:`

Comment: YES! longLongValue didn't do it for me but NSNumberFormatter->numberFromString: did the trick nicely. Huh! now that its pointed out to me, its so obvious there would be a reverse of the NSNumberFormatter->stringFromNumber: method. Why didn't i see that before?     I'll add a code amendment for the benefit of other grasshoppers to follow